# I want to write a c shared lib to called by python

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

This is c 'hello world' code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void hello(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

I using clion IDE and gcc compiler to compile code.
generate a '.dll' shared lib

This is python code

```
import ctypes
dy = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\ssc\CLionProjects\cpython\cmake-build-debug\libcpython.dll')
dy.hello()
```

This can works,it's output

```
Hello, World!
```

but now I add a multi-thread function in c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void hello(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

void *f1()
{
    for(int ct=0;ct<100;ct++)
    {
        printf("thread 1 %d\n",ct);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}
void *f2()
{
    for(int ct=0;ct<100;ct++)
    {
        printf("thread 2 %d\n",ct);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);
}

void print_thread(){
    pthread_t p1;
    pthread_t p2;
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL,f1,NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL,f2,NULL);
    pthread_join(p1,NULL);
    pthread_join(p2,NULL);
}
```

It's can compile to a dll shared lib
but when i use python call,it's can't work .
This is error message

```
C:\Users\ssc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/ssc/CLionProjects/cpython/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ssc\CLionProjects\cpython\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    dy = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:\Users\ssc\CLionProjects\cpython\cmake-buil
d-debug\libcpython.dll')
  File "C:\Users\ssc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.
py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\ssc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.
py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\ssc\CLionProjects\cpython\cma
ke-build-debug\libcpython.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full
path with constructor syntax.
```

I add this code to a c executable program.It's can work

```
C:\Users\ssc\CLionProjects\untitled2\cmake-build-debug\untitled2.exe
thread 1 0
thread 2 0
thread 2 1
thread 2 2
thread 2 3
...
...
```

what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the to find the dll file for pthread. When you compile a shared lib which is dependent on pthreads this will only add a dependency to that dll file from the dll file you create. When calling LoadLibrary this second order dependency needs to be found.

**I'm on Linux and am not too familiar with Windows**, but you can look in the [documentation for LoadLibrary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) about where it searches for dependencies.

On Linux it works for me to take your c-code and compile it with `gcc -shared threads.c -o libthre.so -fPIC -pthread` and then run this in python:

```
import ctypes
lib_th = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libthre.so")
lib_th.hello()
lib_th.print_thread()
```

I can also use `ldd` to verify that it finds the pthread library:

```
$ ldd libthre.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe758ec000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd1cd62b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd1cdc1e000)
```

If the pthread library was not in the search directories I could have specified it either with `rpath` when compiling/linking the shared library or with LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable when running the python program. These does however work differently in Windows, so unfortunately I can't tell you exactly how to do there. Perhaps you can try to copy the pthread dll to the same folder as your own dll file, just as a test.